# How can I use wrapt.decorator adapters to change the signature of unbound methods?

Tags: python, python-decorators, method-signature, wrapt

Below is a MWE of my attempt to change the signature of `MyClass.func` from `(self, a, b, c)` to `(self, x, y, z)`. As you can see from the outputs, the `change_sig` decorator works on functions and also works on the bound method `MyClass().func`, but fails on the unbound method. Is there some sort of magic going on behind the scenes when I assign a callable attribute to a class that keeps this from working?

MWE:

```py
import wrapt
import inspect

def change_sig(func):
    adapter = '(self, x, y, z)'
    @wrapt.decorator(adapter=adapter)
    def wrapper(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
        pass
    wrapped_func = wrapper(func)
    return wrapped_func

@change_sig
def func(self, a, b, c):
    pass

class MyClass:
    @change_sig
    def func(self, a, b, c):
        pass

print('inspect.signature(func):', inspect.signature(func))
print('inspect.signature(MyClass.func):', inspect.signature(MyClass.func))
print('inspect.signature(MyClass().func):', inspect.signature(MyClass().func))

print('inspect.signature(change_sig(MyClass.func)):', inspect.signature(change_sig(MyClass.func)))
MyClass.wrapped_func = change_sig(MyClass.func)
print('inspect.signature(MyClass.wrapped_func):', inspect.signature(MyClass.wrapped_func))
```

Output:

```
inspect.signature(func): (self, x, y, z)
inspect.signature(MyClass.func): (self, a, b, c)
inspect.signature(MyClass().func): (x, y, z)
inspect.signature(change_sig(MyClass.func)): (self, x, y, z)
inspect.signature(MyClass.wrapped_func): (self, a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was traced to a bug in `wrapt`, which is being addressed: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/issues/148